# iOS Facebook app zoomed icon

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-unity-sdk

I have some problems with Facebook sharing. Posted messages look normal via browsers (iOS, PC and Mac versions):

[image: Browsers]

And only FB iOS app shows it wrong:

[image]

What could be the reason for this?

**UPD:** 
I tried 200, 600 and 158 pixels images. Result: 
[image: result]

My code is:

```
public LevelUPFeed (int reachedLevel, string pictureURL) //LevelUPFeed : IFeed
{
    _linkDescription = string.Format("Just reached Level {0} ", reachedLevel);
    _picture = pictureURL;
}

public void SendFeed (IFeed feed, Action<bool> callback)
{
    //... callback creating

    FB.Feed (
        feed.ToId, feed.Link, 
        feed.LinkName, feed.LinkCaption, 
        feed.LinkDescription, feed.Picture, 
        feed.MediaSource, feed.ActionName, 
        feed.ActionLink, feed.Reference, 
        feed.Properties, convertedCallback);
}

feed = new LevelUPFeed (level, pictureUrl);
FBManager.SendFeed (feed, onFeedSent);
```

`feed.LinkName` is "Game Name", `feed.Link` "https://facebook.com", `feed.LinkName` is "Level Up!". All other strings is `string.Empty`

Picture links:

- 600px : https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrJnB.png
- 200px : https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWXLl.png

Answer (score 1):

There are image specifications in the [Open Graph Sharing Best Practices documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images). Use PNG or JPG, 72 dpi, at 600 x 600 pixels for a feed image. The [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.2) documentation says 200 x 200, but the Games feed is specifically mentioned in the best practices document.

> There are two different image sizes to use for game apps:
>
> Open Graph Stories Images appear in a square format. Image ratios for
>   these apps should be 600 x 600 px. Non-open Graph Stories Images
>   appear in a rectangular format. You should use a 1.91:1 image ratio,
>   such as 600 x 314 px.

If this does not answer your question, could you post your API call code?